# IP whitelisting for logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How to whitelist the IP address for the logic app. A service which is called by logic App (using HTTP action) but the service needs the whitelisted to be called to it. SO, how to whitelist for logic APP.

Can we use Azure API management for whitelisting, which publishes logic App, as api management provides static IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct. You can use **API Management** to achieve this.

This would allow for something like this

[image]

And in API Management

[image]

And then in Logic App

[image]

If you want to read more on how to secure logic apps with API management check this article https://marczak.io/posts/2019/08/secure-logic-app-with-api-management/

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly here is a list of Logic App IP addresses to pass to a provider to whitelist.

[Whitelisting and Logic Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2017/05/19/whitelisting-and-logic-apps/)

[Logic App by region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can use APIM for this as Adam has shown.  You can use APIM for just about any security solution involved with APIs (for instance one of our business partners required White Listing and Mutual SSL certificates).  It's all pretty very easy with APIM.