# Logic Apps: HTTP trigger and response time out

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have pretty simple LA that contains just 3 actions. It has HTTP trigger, then it gets some data from SQL server and returns http response with SQL data.

Sometimes, it takes 30-50 seconds to get data from SQL but Logic App in the meantime responses with Timeout error to caller.

> The execution of template action 'Response_2' is failed: the client application timed out waiting for a response from service. This means that workflow took longer to respond than the alloted timeout value. The connection maintained between the client application and service will be closed and client application will get an HTTP status code 504 Gateway Timeout.

Any idea how to increase allowed time for response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn on the `Asynchronous Response`  in the `Settings` of the `Response` action:

[image]

[image]

When you run your logic app longer than its time limit, you will accept 202 `HTTP Code` first:

[image]

It will return a response contains location header:

[image]

You can request the `location` URL, if the status of your logic app still is `running`, it will return 202.

[image]

If the status of your logic app is `Succeeded`, then it will return the results you want.

[image]

You can refer this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app#perform-long-running-tasks-with-the-polling-action-pattern).

Comment: Thank you Frank, I knew about asynchronous response, but I was not aware of that it will return a location where I can additionally check for results. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @MarekBuban, if you have other questions, please let me know!

Comment: any advice how to overcome limitation when Logic App is hidden behind API management and configured to allow calls only from certain IP range - from API management service. When making a call to check the result now, after I've changed response to be asynchronous, I'm getting Unauthorized error as the call to check the result asynchronous is not going through API management gateway.

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944943/ip-whitelisting-for-logic-app) can help you.